# The 12 Zodiac Elements (magic-casting chart idea)

Tags: magic, stars, mythology, classical-elements

**12 Zodiac Elements** (Fire, Earth, Water, Air, Cardinal, Fixed, & Mutable)

Recently I've had the idea to make my elemental magic chart for one of my fantasy stories based off the Zodiac's elemental combinations and their relationship to each other's "three phases." These phases are known as "cardinal," "fixed," and "mutable" to the users of the four elements.

Each one of the 4 Elements can combine/merge with the 3 States of Being.

- Fire=red mage, Earth=yellow mage, Water=green mage, Air=blue mage
- Cardinal=white mage, Fixed=gray mage, Mutable=black mage

All of these different elements combine to make 12 Zodiac Elements on the magic chart, let me explain more. I need to come up with each one of the three phases for each one of the 4 Classical Elements to have it seem like a real feasible thing for the magicians of this fictional to pull off. Each one of these kinds of colored magic are meant to represent their user's Zodiac personality.

ELEMENTS

- Fire/Summer=energy, enthusiasm, inspiration, and impulse
- Earth/Autumn=practicality, utility, material, and conservation
- Water/Winter=emotion, nurture, responsibility, and sympathy
- Air/Spring=communication, social skills, abstract ideals, and mentality

MODES

- Cardinal (first phase) | Solid state? - usher in the season, meet, does something first
- Fixed (second phase) | Liquid state? - middle of season, consolidate, preserve, stand, inertia
- Mutable (third/last phase) | Gas or Plasma state? - end of the season, flexible, adjust, refine, respond, weave, dodge, flow

Tell me what each of "Modes" should be in terms of dividing each one of the 4 Classical Elements (fire, earth, water, air) then into 3 different individual segments. In this world there are 12 Unions/Teams that are basically the 12 Zodiacs themselves. Each has a teacher to lead them towards the same goal. I need one specific element that they can control, possessing a different name from the Element that it's segmented from. (Fire itself can be "flame" but not "fire")

1. Cardinal Fire=Aries, Fixed Fire=Leo, Mutable Fire=Sagittarius

(Flame, Lava, Light, Heaven, Spirit, Illusion?)

2. Cardinal Earth=Capricorn, Fixed Earth=Taurus, Mutable Earth=Virgo

(Rock, Mountain, Wood, Nature, Metal, Poison?)

3. Cardinal Water=Cancer, Fixed Water=Scorpio, Mutable Water=Pisces

(Water, Steam, Coldness, Ice, Void, Darkness?)

4. Cardinal Air=Libra, Fixed Air=Aquarius, Mutable Air=Gemini

(Wind, Space, Thunder, Lightning, Time, Sound?)

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to do your idea generation for you.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the Chinese Zodiac, where their various metal, fire, wood, water & earth and so-on, are combined with the animal sign for each given year. Here is a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac

Comment: Hello @WaterFire! I recommend checking out the [help] to learn more about how the site works. You have asked similar brainstorming questions before and they do not work well on StackExchange because we are expecting clear questions and clear answers. If you want you can give the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on [meta] a try. Users can get feedback on the general stuff there, such as on-topic/off-topic, before releasing a question onto the main site.

Comment: Hello @WaterFire.RTH. I've noticed that you posted multiple similar questions in the past where you asked for general feedback about some concept you made. Most of these questions were put on hold. This means that these questions were not considered suitable for Worldbuilding.SE by the community. Please refrain from posting such questions in the future. Rather try to ask questions which describe a specific problem and ask for a solution.

Comment: That's really jumbled. Also, YOU GOT THE ELEMENTS WRONG!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Whatever you want them to be

With magic thats pretty much the answer you'll get for everything. [There are some rules I suggest following](https://www.erindorpress.com/2013/11/world-building-magic-systems/) and [if you fancy making it rational](https://mythcreants.com/blog/how-to-create-a-rational-magic-system/).

Make sure your ideas are self consistent - so your cardinal fire person isn't prancing around shooting ice out their hands - but aside from that you don't need anyone else's input on a reality check because **magic is you creating your *own* reality** asking for input on details within this reality is going to be very opinion based.